# My Discord bot (using canvas) is not working

Tags: canvas, discord.js

So i put the correct id to CHANNEL_ID part.
It should create a goodbye message with a picture. But somehow it doesnt work. I dont know maybe i should put it in the index.js? please help...

[here is the goodbye.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQd5Q.png)

```
const channelId = "CHANNEL_ID";
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (member) => {
        const { guild } = member
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage(
            path.join(__dirname, './goodbye.png')
            )
        let x = 0
        let y = 0
        ctx.drawImage(background, x, y)
        const pfp = await Canvas.loadImage(
            member.user.displayAvatarURL({
              format: 'png',
            })
          )
          x = canvas.width / 2 - pfp.width / 2
          y = 25
          ctx.drawImage(pfp, x, y)
          // Display user text
          ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff' // White text
          ctx.font = '35px sans-serif'
          let text = `Goodbye ${member.user.tag}!`
          x = canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2
          ctx.fillText(text, x, 60 + pfp.height)
          // Display member count
          ctx.font = '30px sans-serif'
          text = `Now we have ${guild.memberCount} members!`
          x = canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2
          ctx.fillText(text, x, 100 + pfp.height)
            
          const message = `<@${member.id}>`
          const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer())
          channel.send('', attachment)
   })

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is it not doing anything altogether?

Comment: Actually im not getting any errors. In terminal nothing shows up. :(

Answer (score 0):

We do need to know **what** isn't working.

- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

If you updated discord.js to v13 you should change the
`channel.send('', attachment)` line to `channel.send({ files: [attachment] });`

If you're still on discord.js v13, you should double check if this exported function is actually receiving the `client` object whenever you're calling it: `require('path/to/file/with/this/code')(client);`

If both of these don't fix your issue, we will need some more information. The problem might be that you're providing a relative path to the [Canvas#loadImage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas#loadimage) function instead of an absolute path, but if it couldn't be loaded, you would have received an error in your console.